# Cannot deactivate Newsstand in iTunesConnect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, newsstand-kit

I have uploaded an App which is Newsstand enabled to iTunesConnect.

It seems not possible to de-activate it again for the app.

Unchecking "Newsstand" just prompts a "contact support" dialog...

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone does occur the same situation - the solution is quite simple:

- just remove the build you have uploaded
- disable newsstand

And you will be able to save the changes you made and continue without NewsStand

Note: Once your app goes live with NewsStand, you will not be able to go back!